# django order's problem

Tags: django

blow is my database:

```
class TestCases(TmstafServerModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class TestRunSummary(TmstafServerModel):
    testResult = models.ForeignKey(TestResult)
    testCases = models.ForeignKey(TestCases)
    platform = models.ForeignKey(Platform)
```

I want to get data order by testcase's name, such as:

```
all_fail_case = TestRunSummary.objects.all().order_by('testCases.name')
```

but it not work, how can i get all records in TestRunSummary which ordering by testCases name?
thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `__` instead of `.` like described in the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#order-by-fields). Alternatively you can also specify a default ordering for the TestCase model and sort by `testCases`.

```
all_fail_case = TestRunSummary.objects.order_by('testCases__name').all()
```

Comment: Thank you! Can i ask you why not use TestRunSummary.objects.all().order_by('testCases__name')

Since in order condition, it's right to write order_by() after all()
thank you!

Comment: @Yuan - it's redundant - `all` is only useful where you need to definitely have a `QuerySet` (per the documentation at http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all)